# SVG breaking Svelte app after minification

Tags: svelte, vite, minify

I'm working on an app for a directory and the pagination for some reason is breaking during minification (vite and svelte configured). When minification is turned off, everything works fine. I've pinpointed the issue to an SVG element that, when it's removed, makes the app work fine even after minification.

Could anyone help with figuring out why that's happening?

```
    <script lang="ts">
      import { createEventDispatcher} from 'svelte';
      export let paginateItem = []
      export let currentPage: number = 1;
      export let total = 0;
      export let ref;
      const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
    
      const paginateActions = {
        selectPageNum(num) {
          
          dispatch('paginatefn', num)
        }
      }
    </script>

    <svelte:options tag="pagination-component" />
    <nav class="paginate" {ref}>
      <ul class="pagination row">
        {#if currentPage > 15}
       

<!-- Inserting an SVG below here breaks the pagination after minification -->

   <svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon--chevron-thin-left" on:click={() => paginateActions?.selectPageNum(currentPage - 1)}>
       <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon--chevron-thin-left"></use>
   </svg> 

<!-- Inserting an SVG above here breaks the pagination after minification -->

          <li>
            <a href={'javascript:void(0)'} class="{currentPage === total ? 'active' : ''}" on:click={() => paginateActions.selectPageNum(1)}>
              { 1 }...
            </a>
          </li>
    
        {/if}
        {#each paginateItem as itm}
          <li>
            <a href={'javascript:void(0)'} class="{currentPage === itm ? 'active' : ''}" on:click={() => paginateActions.selectPageNum(itm)}>
              { itm }
            </a>
          </li>
        {/each}
        {#if total > 15 && currentPage < total}
          <li>
            <a href={'javascript:void(0)'} class="{currentPage === total ? 'active' : ''} link" on:click={() => paginateActions.selectPageNum(total)}>
              ...{ total }
            </a>
          </li>
          <svg aria-hidden="true" class="icon icon--chevron-thin-right" on:click={() => paginateActions.selectPageNum(currentPage + 1)}>
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon--chevron-thin-right"></use>
          </svg>
        {/if}
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

To narrow things down, when I replace the broken SVG with the working SVG (icon--chevron-thin-right) the minification *also* breaks. So I'm not sure why placing an SVG in that first conditional makes everything go wrong?

Comment: That is invalid HTML, by the way. `ul` are generally only supposed to contain `li` elements (`script` and `template` are also allowed).

Comment: Thanks for that @H.B. adding LI tags around each SVG didn't change anything but the code is now at least valid